# JavaScriptの処理を登録するパターンについて

Tags: javascript

どのように実装すべきなのかわからなかいので質問させていただきます。

下のコードは、現在時刻を垂れ流すwebsocketサーバに接続するコードです。
「関数Xを登録しそれを毎分N秒に実行する。ただし毎時間M分で登録を解除する」といったことをしたい場合どのように実装すべきでしょうか？

一応自分で書いてみたのですが、awaitで処理が完了するのを待てなかったり、コールバック地獄になるようなコードになってしまうので助言をいただきたいと思います。

```
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://websocketstest.com/service');
ws.onopen = () => {
    ['connected,', 'version,hybi-draft-13', 'echo,test message', 'timer,']
        .forEach(c=>ws.send(c));
};

let events = []
ws.onmessage = (blob) => {
        if (events.length === 0) return;
        const messageDate = new Date(blob.data.split(',')[1]);
        for (const event of events) {
            if (event.func(messageDate) === true) {
                event.valid = false;
            }
        }
        events = events.filter(s => s.valid === true);
}

function register(func) {
    events.push({
        func: func,
        valid: true
    });
}

const N = 30;
const M = 5;
const X = ()=>{console.log("FOFOOOOOO");};
(async () => {
    register(msg => {
        console.log(msg);
        if (msg.getSeconds() % N === 0) {
            X()
        }
        if (msg.getHours() % M === 0) {
            return true; // 終了
        }
    });
    console.log('end');
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Observer/Observableのパターンで作ればいいのではないかと思います。ObserverはObservableに登録して、Observableは任意のタイミングで登録者にメッセージを送ります。

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fbL4cark/2/)

```
ws.onopen = () => {
    ['connected,', 'version,hybi-draft-13', 'echo,test message', 'timer,']
        .forEach(c=>ws.send(c));
};
```

この部分はよく分からなかったのでそのままにしときました。

> awaitで処理が完了するのを待てなかったり

`await`は`Promise`オブジェクトに対してしか使えないので、今の場合自分でわざわざ`Promise`を返すような関数を作る必要がありますが、別に使わなくていいと思います。

> コールバック地獄になるようなコードになってしまう

今の場合コールバックの連鎖が必要ないので callback hell にはならないと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ところで例えば上記例から発展して「M分に終了した後、毎時間Sで関数Yを実行しT日に終了」というような処理を加えたい場合、timer.unsubscribeの後にtimer.subscribeを呼び出す方法しか思い浮かばなく、インデントが深くなるのが気になるのですが他に手段はありますか？

Comment: 事前に次の`Observer`を作っておけば、インデントは深くならないと思います。[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fbL4cark/3/)

Comment: 確かにそうでした。ありがとうございます。自分で使う簡単なライブラリを作っていて、そうなると一番気になるのは記述の順序なんですが(後に実行する関数を先に書く必要がある)、考えたところPromiseを使ってしまう方法しか思いつきませんでした。karamarimoさんの手法のままで解決は可能でしょうか

Comment: すみません事前に書く必要はありませんでした。jsでは[hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)により変数宣言文の前にその変数を参照することができます。なので[自然な順番](https://jsfiddle.net/fbL4cark/5/)で書けます。Promiseはあまり慣れていないので、いいやり方かわからないですが[こう](https://jsfiddle.net/ttgf4pjg/1/)できます。

Comment: わかりました。できれば記述する量が少ない方が良いので後者の方が好みではあるのですが、複数登録すると上書きされてしまいますね。機能している前者の方法で進めたいと思います。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

元々のコードが色々と入り組んでいますが以下のような感じではダメなのでしょうか？

```
ws.onmessage = (blob) => {
  const msg = new Date(blob.data.split(',')[1]);
  if (msg.getMinutes() < M) {
    if (msg.getSeconds() === S) { X(); }
  }
}
```